# Why is the data not stored in elasticsearch?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I use NEST for requests in elasticsearch. When saving data to elasticsearch, an error occurs.

Request: PUT: /strategy/30772377 {"id": 1, "name": "strategy1"}

When saving, NEST returns an error.

My code:

```cs
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new StaticConnectionPool(uri));

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var response = await client.IndexAsync(
                    model,
                    x => x.Type(indexType).Index(indexName),
                    cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

---

Error:

> NEST.Response.DebugInformation:
>
> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on PUT:
>   /strategy/30772377
>
> Audit trail of this API call:
>    - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:51.9406716
>    - [2] CancellationRequested: Took: 00:00:00
>
> OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The
>   request was aborted: The request was canceled.. Call: Status code
>   unknown from: PUT /strategy/30772377 --->
>
> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was
>   canceled.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.
>
> d__5`1.MoveNext()    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---
>
> Request: {"id": 1, "name": "strategy1"}
>
> Response:

Answer (score 0):

The audit trail in the debug information indicates that the request was eventually cancelled using the `CancellationToken`. The audit event before this indicates a bad response from Elasticsearch; `response.ServerError` will contain the error from Elasticsearch if there is something wrong with the request.

Comment: ServerError is empty. ServerError: . Result: Error. ApiCall: Unsuccessful low level call on PUT: /strategy/1

Comment: Can you show the entire JSON response from Elasticsearch? You can use something like Fiddler to capture it: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-fiddler.html

Also, can you show a complete, reproducible example that demonstrates the issue you're seeing? You can edit the question to add these e.g. what `model` is, `indexType`, `indexName`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Most likely the problem is not in the Elasticsearch, but in the hard disk. Today, the system administrator will change the disk, tomorrow I will check.

Comment: The problem was in the hard disk. After replacing it, everything works without errors. Thanks you for the answer.